# When go to another View, .push works only once

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I would like to have a custom menu (with html or buttons, but not as "Ext.tab.Panel") that points to the specific View I want.
I managed to change the Views on click, but now I have another problem...

On first run of the app, everything works fine... 
..App starts.. I click on View where I have the list of items... click on an item and that pushes another view with details. Works? works! :)

.....but here is the problem:
- when I go to a view (Ext.NavigationView) that has a list, and from there I push the "home" icon to get the "Main.js" view I return to "home" (as expected),
- when I click on the link that goes again to the same list, it shows me the list of items, but WON'T OPEN details of that item again (reember we pushed another view to show this)

Can someone help me out? What am I doing wrong?

Here are some codes of my app:

**controller/Details.js**

```
Ext.define('SkSe.controller.Details', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {

    refs: {
        placesContainer:'placesContainer'
    },
    control: {
        //get me the list inside the places which is inside placesContainer
        'placesContainer places list':{
            itemsingletap:'onItemTap'
            //itemtap:'onItemTap'
        }

    }
}
,
onItemTap:function(list,index,target,record){

    console.log('You clicked an item');


    this.getPlacesContainer().push({
        xtype:'details',
        title:record.data.name,
        data:record.data
    })


}
```

});

**controller/Main.js**

```
Ext.define('SkSe.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    control: {
        //define the name of the function to call when button is pressed
        homeButton: {tap: 'goToHome'},
        liveButton: {tap: 'goToLive'}
    },

    refs: {
        //button must have action='something' for reference
        homeButton: 'button[action=goToHome]',
        liveButton: 'button[action=goToLive]'
    }
},
```

//define all the functions below

```
goToHome: function() {//called whenever the button is tapped
    //debug for tapping. See in console what buton you tapped so we can assign some action
    console.log('You clicked on a button that goes to Home (trouble!)');

    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem({xtype: 'main'},{type: 'slide',direction: 'left'});


},

goToLive: function() {//called whenever the button is tapped
    //debug for tapping. See in console what buton you tapped so we can assign some action
    console.log('You clicked on a button that goes to Live');

    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem({xtype: 'live'},{type: 'slide',direction: 'left'});

}
```

});

**view/PlacesContainer.js**

```
Ext.define('SkSe.view.PlacesContainer',{
extend:'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype:'placesContainer',


config:{
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'places'

        },
        {
            xtype:'toolbar',
            docked:'bottom',

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    title: 'Go to Akcije (placesContainer)',
                    iconCls: 'icon-akcije',
                    action:'goToHome'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    title: 'Go Live (live.js)',
                    iconCls: 'icon-live',
                    action:'goToLive'
                }
            ]

        }


    ]
}
```

});

**view/Places.js**

```
Ext.define('SkSe.view.Places',{
extend:'Ext.Panel',
xtype:'places',

config:{

    autoLoad:true,

    title:'Akcije',
    iconCls:'icon-akcije',
    layout:'fit',
    items:[

        {
            xtype:'list',
            store:'Places',

            itemTpl:'<img src="resources/icons/{icon}"><h1>{name:ellipsis(25)}</h1><h3>{stamps}</h3>',
            itemCls:'place-entry'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Comment: Any error in the console when you try to push the second time ?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a problem similar to this when using non-descriptive refs. Try adding an id to your buttons and referencing them by that.

i.e. `homeButton: '#homeButton'`